# Decoding barcodes with pyzbar, opencv from folder of images

Tags: python, opencv, decode

There are images in this folder which contain one or more barcodes. My task at work is to sort through them and rename based on the study number (found in or below the barcode).

More information on the issue: 
There are specific barcodes that I want to extract. Since there are two types of barcodes (with study number or with Airwaybill Number).

Study number has a length of 13 numbers (they are **always** numbers): 
study (6) + patient (4) + visit (3)
Example:
123456 7890 123

The exceptions are not appended to the list but they are printed alongside the respective filename it was found in.

I would like to iterate through all the items in the folder and decode each one.

## Code

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
import cv2

mypath = '/Users/Eric/Desktop/test'

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
onlyimg = []
barcode = []
notbarcode = []
for x in onlyfiles:
    im = join(mypath,x)
    onlyimg.append(im)


def decode(im) : 
  # Find barcodes and QR codes
  decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(im)

  # Print results
  for obj in decodedObjects:
      try: 
          barcode.append(int(obj.data)) 
      except Exception as e:
          print(str(e))
          print(f)

#print('Type : ', obj.type)
#code = print('Number : ', obj.data,'\n')
#barcode.append(code)

  return decodedObjects 
# Main 
if __name__ == '__main__':

  # Read image
  for img in onlyimg:
      im = cv2.imread(img)

  decodedObjects = decode(im)
```

However, with this code it only reads the first and decodes the first image.

I have tried running the following code in order to try and loop through the items:

```
for img in glob.glob(folder + "*.jpg"):
      im = cv2.imread(img)
```

Yet it does not help.

Running the entire code results in:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'615X10394435'
2218400280901.jpg
```

Printing the list barcodes results in:

```
print(barcodes)
[2218400280903, 2218400280901]
```

These two results are fine, since the one that is going to be used to rename is the one with the smallest visit number so in this case 2218400280901.

Yet, the code only decoded the first image, and it did not loop through the entire images. Is it because I did not include the iteration in the for-loop? or where is the mistake, that I clearly cannot see?

Thank you all for your time and help!!

Comment: Could you post the input images?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the output of `print(obj.data)` before the line `barcode.append(...`.

Comment: @nathancy I cannot show the image because it is a work-related document.

Comment: @Stovfl print(obj.data) yields : b'2218400280903', b'2218400280901'

Comment: @EricWalzthöny: You hav a `X` within `b'615X10394435'` which can't converted to `int`. As you allready have  a `try: ... except: ...` block this is not the culprit.

Comment: @EricWalzthöny: Your last line `decodedObjects = decode(im)` has indentation error. It sould indent to the same level as `im = cv2...`

Comment: @stovfl You are right! Thank you for seeing what I couldnt!